# variable of integration not in function

Tags: definite-integrals

what is

$\int_0^x ax^2 dy$

additionally, how is this described when the variable of integration is not in the function? I'm not sure how to research this.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no real term for it, as you're treating $x$ as a constant while doing the integration. It's as if it were any other more familiar constant, like $\pi$ or $\sqrt 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^x ax^2dy=ax^2\int_0^xdy=ax^2\cdot y\bigg|_0^x=ax^2(x-0)=ax^3$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{x} ax^{2} dy = a x^{2} \int_{0}^{x}dy = a x^{2}y|_{0}^{x} = ax^{3}$

Note that the function $f(x) = ax^{2}$ independent of the variable y, therefore, in this case, it is a constant function and follows the calculations above.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression $x$ is a free variable (that appears twice) and $y$ is a bound variable.

In general: $$\int_0^xcdy=[cy]^x_0=cx-c0=cx$$because the antiderivative of constant $c$ as a function on variable $y$ is $cy$.

Applying that here (where $c=ax^2$) we find that:$$\int_0^xax^2dy=ax^2x=ax^3$$

---

Further note that we can write also $\int_0^xcf(y)dy$ where function $f$ is prescribed by $y\mapsto1$ taking away the "objection" that the variable of integration is not present in the integrand.

So there is no essential need to pay any attention to that phenomenom.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of $y$, $ax^2$ is just a constant.

So without limits: $$\int ax^2 dy =ax^2y+C$$

Hence $$\int_0^x ax^2 dy =ax^2(x-0)=ax^3$$